# How do I copy the legend of the corresponding plot as well as the plot himself into another plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm working with the following Code to copy a saved plot into another.

```
fig1 = openfig('ABC.fig');
fig2 = openfig('DEF.fig', 'invisible');
copyobj(fig2.Children.Children, fig1.Children);
```

This works fine, as long as I'm not using a legend in `fig2`, then I get a Error message for using too many input arguments in `copyobj`. In the documentation I learnt, that `copyobj` doesn't copy the context menu of legends, so I'm asking for your help in copying the legend as well.

Comment: So this is just a hunch but I remember matlab altering the figure object when using legends... Have you tried: `copyobj(fig2.Children, fig1.Children);` when using `legend()`?

Comment: @LNiederha yes I've tried that. The following Error occurs: "Error using
matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend/connectCopyToTree
A legend must be copied with its associated
axes. Use a vector input with COPYOBJ in order
to copy the legend and axes together." How do i copy that legend? That's what I was trying to do the whole time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157737-why-does-copyobj-return-an-error-when-copying-legends-or-colorbars-in-matlab-r2014b):

```
plot(rand(2))
l = legend('show'); % legend
ax = gca; % associated axes

fnew = figure;
copyobj([l,ax],fnew) 
% This is what the error was telling you. 
% You need to pass your axes object 
% along with you legend object as an array of graphic objects
```

> [l,ax]
>
> ans =
>
> 1×2 graphics array:
>
> ```
> Graphics    Graphics
> ```